# Youtube JS API Causes Error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

I am attempting to embed a Youtube Video inside a webpage. I am using the Youtube Javascript API to embed/load the videos.

**My Problem:** The video embeds inside Internet Explorer but there are many javascript errors when I inspect the console. These errors mean I cannot replay the video, make the video grow, or really do anything. These javascript errors do not occur in Firefox or Chrome just IE.

Console Error:

> SCRIPT87: Invalid Argument.
>   www-embed-player-vf1m....js line 211 character 405

Heres my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Y6mk/1/) that demonstrates the problem. Remember to RUN it in IE to see the problem.

My code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.youtube.com/player_api" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadYouTubeVideo(uid) {
        setTimeout( function() {
                    var id         = uid;
                    var instPlayer = new YT.Player(id, {
                        height: '240',
                        width: '426',
                        enablejsapi: 1,
                        suggestedQuality: 'highres',
                        videoId: uid});
            }, 500);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Run in IE and look at console</p>

<div id="Go3u2zw6fbE"></div><script> loadYouTubeVideo("Go3u2zw6fbE"); </script>

</body>
<html>
```

Comment: Your fiddle is empty ;) ... unless is http://jsfiddle.net/89gxN/1/

Comment: In your jsfiddle, use `no wrap - in <head>` mode, and create the missing functions `onPlayerReady` and `onPlayerStateChange` then IE shouldn't throw any errors ... your forked jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2Y6mk/

Comment: @JFK woops. I've fixed it now.

Comment: @JFK any ideas why the IE error is occuring or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was running the Javascript code from a local HTML file and not from a HTML file over the internet.

I  guess when you run the Youtube Javascript API in a local HTML file (inside Internet Explorer only) the youtube video wont play. Even if I click 'Allow Javascript' it still wont play.

Comment: Not a perfect answer because it "should" work over local, as it does with Firefox (I'm referring to my own code, having same error.)